# struts 2 jquery plugin multi select

Tags: jquery, plugins, struts2

I'm using the jquery plugin for struts 2 and I'm strugling to make select `multi="true"` to work.

This is the code I'm using to describe the tag:

```
      <sj:select id="rolePermissions" href="%{permissonAll}" onCompleteTopics="bla"  cssClass="multiselect" dataType="json" multiple="true"
                       list="permissions" listValue="name" name="role.permission" 
                       listKey="id" />
```

If I put single selection it works but no way I can put multiselection.
I tried everything what comes to my mind`("1,2","[1,2]")` and every combination with every possible delimiter but no luck.

Comment: you want user to select more than one option?

Comment: yes, but I lose 2 days and get sources and started to debug what is actually going on there, and as I can see preselection for multi selections is not implemented

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but based on the doc here is what we can try

```
  <sj:select id="rolePermissions" href="%{permissonAll}" onCompleteTopics="bla" 
    cssClass="multiselect" dataType="json" multiple="true" 
    list="permissions" listValue="name" name="role.permission" 
    listKey="id" />
```

We can create an array or Collection(say list) which we want to preselect If one of the keys equals one of the values in the Collection or Array it wil be selected.
So if we want to select 2 items say whose keys are `1` and `2` we need to create a list in our action class like

```
Public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

    private List<String> preSelection;
    //getter and setter for the preSelection

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        preSelection=new ArrayList<String>();
        preSelection.add("1");
         preSelection.add("1");
         return SUCCESS;
    }  


}
```

and finally the tag should be something like

```
  <sj:select id="rolePermissions" href="%{permissonAll}" onCompleteTopics="bla" 
    cssClass="multiselect" dataType="json" multiple="true" 
    list="permissions" listValue="name" name="role.permission" 
    listKey="id" value="%{preSelection}" />
```

since as per the doc:

> value----->Preset the value of input element.

hope this will help you a bit

Comment: thanks for your help, but this doesn't seems to help. I will abandon jquery plugin for struts2 and do it by using pure jquery.

Comment: it is not auto selecting the value? or anything else.Honestly i never liked this idea of using wrapper around Jquery when its so much flexible in itself

Answer (score 0):

Add multiselect="true" to your sj:grid parameters